# Google Cloud Endpoints Framework 2 (Java) Error Meaning and Origin?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints-v2

Migrating to Framework 2. Using Java 8. What is the below error message trying to tell me? What might be wrong with my class annotations or web.xml? I am using Servlets 3.1.0 for other servlets. Does this enter into the equation?

```
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyLogger warn: 
    Error for /_ah/api/taxdochubapi/v1/taxdoc/retrievewithguid
    (JettyLogger.java:29)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
    com/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Function
    at com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet.init(EndpointsServlet.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:499)
    ...

// Relevant annotation
@ApiMethod( name = "taxdocument.retrieve.withguid", 
            path = "taxdoc/retrievewithguid", 
            httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET )
public Map<String, String> retrieveTaxDocForGuid( @Named("guid") String guid ) {

<!-- web.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
    <servlet>
         <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
             <param-name>services</param-name>
             <param-value>com.taxdochub.endpoints.spi.TaxDocHubApiDocuments</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <init-param>
             <param-name>restricted</param-name>
             <param-value>false</param-value>
         </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
         <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Is this Java 8 or 7 runtime?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by my leaving a v1 dependency in my pom.xml file. After removing the below dependency, it started working.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
        <version>${appengineVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
```